# OSB set external ip in generated wsdl

Tags: soap, wsdl, weblogic, osb, oracle-fusion-middleware

We are using Oracle Service Bus 12c. On our developer server, the default domain configured in jDeveloper runs. The OSB exposes the defined SOAP services locally on port 7101. We wanted these services to be accessible also externally, so we forwarded a port from a firewall server.

Now the SOAP service can be called from the outside, but the generated WSDL (at [serviceurl]?wsdl) states localhost in the address tag at the binding as the location of the server instead of the firewall's IP.

I have tried to set the *frontend host* and the *remote address overwrite* properties under *protocols* -> *http* for the server, but neither changed the value in the generated WSDL.

Where can I configure the server location for the generated WSDLs?

Comment: if you have just one managed server it should be part of a cluster also.

Comment: What do you mean with 'generated WSDL'? Never heard of it. In our projects we have to create our own WSDL and import it into the SOA Suite. You can then change the address by editing the WSDL.